# On removing Linux from an HP laptop, is it posible?

Tags: windows-7, linux, laptop, partitioning

I've got an HP Pavilion, it has factory settings (just formatted C with the recovery partition).

I'm eager to try Linux and learn Ruby on Rails.

Sadly I'm so afraid to mess with my Windows so I've got these questions:

- Will I be able to erase Linux and restore my windows, and it's capability to rule the whole HDD? (excluding recovery partitions)
- My laptop, it has another Operative System (or something like that) which is activated from inside windows, will I be able to enter that SO again? (It's called HP QuickWeb)
- Heard it's hard to remove a Linux, If i decide i didn't like Mint, or I just want to try Ubuntu, or any other distro, will I be able to do it?
- Will this mess with the recovery partition? The last format C: I did was godly, it took 20 minutes to wipe a 300GB HDD and install windows to factory settings, will this ability hold after I install Linux?

Comment: Why not add Linux as a dual boot?  You don't need to remove Windows at all.  If you decide to remove Linux, just reuse its partitions for whatever you want or extend the Windows partition to reclaim the space.  A 300 GB HDD is plenty big for that.

Comment: My bad, i forgot to mention i wanted to DualBoot on top of everything !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you provide some details about what's there now and what you want to do?  There are endless options.  If you really want to wipe what's there, clone the HDD so you can put it back the way it was.  But if you're going to have a 2nd drive for that purpose, you could just do your experimenting on it and leave the original alone.

Comment: Details:
Laptop HP Pavillion 16dvla, currently no CD reader, Windows 7 Installed in C. 2 extra partitions with Recovery tools (factory settings recovery) and HP_TOOLS (idk what is this) ACtually 230GB free, I want to install (dual boot) either LMint, Ubunt or Debian. I want to learn Ruby for web programming. In the case I don't like Linux, i want to recover my PC just as factory settings and no trace i Ever used LInux on it. As it is a 8 year old laptop, I'd like something lightweight ...

Comment: Ofc I'd need to use this linux distro to run a web server for tests.  I have recovery disks for the Laptop, but since it has no CD Drive (it's broken or something, hardware's fault) im not eager to find out i can't even use them via USB.

Comment: This can be done without affecting Windows, although it's possible to mess up if you're not careful (I accidentally wiped Win XP from an old computer by not understanding an install option).  So clone your HDD for safety.  The process is just to shrink the Windows partition (utility is part of Windows), then use the space for Linux partitions.  (cont'd)

Comment: If it's an old laptop with MBR, make the new partition an extended partition, then break it into as many logical partitions as you need for Linux.  Linux will add GRUB, which will include Windows in its menu.  You can reuse those partitions to try other distros, or delete the partitions and extend the Windows partition back into the space.

Comment: Thank you a lot, one last question, will UEFI or BIOS  stand in my way? I don't even know what are those.

Comment: Ruby on rails isn't exactly very heavy. The smart money's on running it on a VM, especially if you're new to linux. Virtualbox's perfectly good for this sort of thing, and you don't risk your windows install.

Comment: UEFI vs. BIOS refers to the mechanism used to boot.  An 8 yr old Windows 7 machine should be BIOS, using a Master Boot Record (MBR) as described in the link you found.  The installation just needs to be consistent with your hardware, and it looks like your link should be.  Good luck.  BTW, it's a good idea to learn as much as possible before you start changing things.  Google any terms you don't understand, or ask questions, before you start.

Comment: Well well... now this: 
-Found that the space i made for LinuxM is "unusable", google says "You can't have more than 4 primary", I have this: HP_TOOLS, Recovery, Windows partition, System. So I can't install anything. I made the recovery disks and I trust myself to keep 'em safe. But I don't trust my family or anyone else. (not even trust HP will have em when I need, anyway my PC doesn't have CD reader rofl) If someone could tell me HP_TOOLS can be recovered like nothing i'll feel much better. So far google gives some links to HPSupport which doesn't work or are for DV6 Laptops (i am dv4)

Comment: If you want to keep it simple and safe, just use an external USB drive for Linux.  Even USB 2.0 will be fast enough for this to be practical (I've done that for years).  Set boot priority in BIOS to try USB first.  If the drive is plugged in, GRUB will include Windows on your main drive, so you can leave it plugged in and boot whatever you want.  If it's unplugged, the laptop works the same as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, it's very helpful!
http://www.thpc.info/dual/7/db_mint17_grub_mbr_on_win7.html

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/How-to-repartition-HDD-of-HP-notebook-with-pre-installed/td-p/742019

This is a far better solution! ERASE SYSTEM PARTITION (not joking)
When in recovery mode for windows, to access cmd i had to "load drivers" and right click cmd and run as administrator. did the partition erase, restart, and windows will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on rails isn't exactly very heavy. The smart money's on running it on a VM, especially if you're new to linux. Virtualbox's perfectly good for this sort of thing, and you don't risk your windows install.

If you *must* dualboot.
I recommend making restore disks at a minimum (so you can wipe and rebuild), and that with a full disk backup if you want to be safe.

I've also had reasonable luck running a secondary hard disk (over sata or at least USB 3.0 if you can! but I've had lightweight linux installs running off USB 2.0 keys ) installed the same way you'd install linux the normal way with its own bootloader.